# How can I debug if resetting a cabal sandbox does not solve dependency errors?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a curious situation. I have a package that used to work properly and for no apparent reason stopped running `cabal test`.

```
$ cabal test
The sandbox was created after the package was already configured.
Re-configuring with most recently used options. If this fails, please run
configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring dump-0.2.6...
cabal: The following package dependencies were requested
--dependency='interpolatedstring-perl6=interpolatedstring-perl6-0.9.0-806887e26af0b5e9d9f99d13a2b9d08c'
--dependency='hspec=hspec-2.1.8-4133af4aaac7344a4e3a6a8a90be2cb8'
--dependency='haskell-src-meta=haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.10-044625c00cdf446dac843874b8e39126'
however the given installed package instance does not exist.
```

I tried to reinstall the sandbox by running

```
cabal sandbox delete
cabal sandbox init
cabal install
```

Which helps not.

Then I noticed the text saying `The sandbox was created after the package was already configured.` So I try to run

```
cabal configure
```

After which I get

```
$ cabal test     
Re-configuring with test suites enabled. If this fails, please run configure
manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring dump-0.2.6...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
hspec -any
```

What might be going wrong? What can I do as the next step to try to debug this?

#### Versions

```
$ echo {cabal,ghc}" --version;" | sh
cabal-install version 1.22.2.0
using version 1.22.2.0 of the Cabal library 
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.1
```

Comment: Don't you need to `cabal install --enable-tests` and/or `cabal configure --enable-tests`?

Comment: That seems to work, thanks @ReidBarton. Could you change your comment to be an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `cabal install` to install the dependencies of your tests you must use the `--enable-tests` options. (For most packages that you install you don't plan to run the tests, and then installing the dependencies of the tests is potentially a waste of time.) Based on the error messages in your post I guess you must also use `cabal configure --enable-tests` in order to use `cabal test`; I'm not sure what the purpose of that is.